# Migrate from EF to EF Core. Unloaded entity in the For Loop

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-4

We embark on a journey to migrate an existing EF4 project to EF7.

We stumbled upon a leak that will lead to many undetected bugs (no build errors).

In the EF4 project, we rely on Lazy Loading to get the data of related entities. For example:

```
var items = db.Items.GetXXXById(id);
var filteredItems = (from item in items 
                        where item.StatusId == 1
                        select item).ToList();
var childrens = from item in filteredItems
                where item.StatusId == 1
                from children in item.Childrens
                select children;

Debug.WriteLine(childrens.Count()); // This returned 0 on EF7 but the correct value on EF4.
```

The above code will return a correct value on EF4 but it returns zero on EF7.

To mitigate the above, we will have to add an "Include" to eager load the children. For example:

```
var items = db.Items.GetXXXById(id);
var filteredItems = (from item in items 
                        where item.StatusId == 1
                        select item).Include(i => i.Children).ToList();
var childrens = from item in filteredItems
                where item.StatusId == 1
                from children in item.Childrens
                select children;

Debug.WriteLine(childrens.Count()); // Both EF4 and EF7 returns the correct value.
```

But, without the build error thrown, we will have to check all our queries to figure out what we need to "Include". Is there a way or a tool that helps detect such "leak"?

Comment: If you are relying on lazy loading in EF4, why don't you activate [EF Core Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)? In EF Core it's just not enabled by default as in classic EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [Lazy loading with proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#lazy-loading-with-proxies) in your DbContext class like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

This setting will work like EF4 that is lazy loading enabled by default.

IMHO, It's not a best practice for many circumstances. You should consider turn off lazy loading by default and taking care of the relationship between entities to avoid [N+1 problem](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/common-entity-framework-problems-n-1/).